# Проблемы при выделении кода в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Когда я пытаюсь выделить код, для того, чтобы скопировать, появляется этот белый мигающий прямоугольник (sorry, не знаю, как это явление называется правильно). Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне сделать, чтобы этого не происходило

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Use Block Caret https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988774/how-to-change-pycharm-5-0-1-cursor

Comment: @Jack_oS, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

нажмите на клавиатуре кнопку Insert(Ins) :)

Comment: это помогает выключить то, что уже появилось, однако при следующем выделении всё повторяется

Comment: в общем, суть вопроса заключается в том, как решить эту проблему навсегда

Comment: IdeaVim плагин не установлен случайно?

Comment: IdeaVim установлен

Comment: выше ссылку уже скинули на лечение плагина, или просто его удалите

Comment: премного благодарен)